# cassandra INSERT fails after a lot inserts with : "Operation timed out"

Tags: c++, cassandra

I use the cassandra-c++-driver to write 100000 rows in a 100-columns table like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassandra.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
CassFuture *connect_future = NULL;
CassCluster *cluster = NULL;
CassSession *session = NULL;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> dis;


int COLUMNS_COUNT = 100;
using namespace std;

void insertQ() {

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    for (int row = 0; row < 10000; ++row) {
        string columns;
        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS_COUNT; ++i) {
            columns += "name" + to_string(i) + " , ";
        }

        string result = "INSERT INTO mykeyspace.users2 (user_id,";
        result += columns;
        result += "lname) VALUES (";


        string values = to_string(dis(gen) % 50000000) + ",";

        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS_COUNT; ++i) {
            values += "'name" + to_string(dis(gen)) + "' , ";
        }

        values += " 'lname" + to_string(dis(gen) % 20) + "'";
        result += values;
        result += ");";


        CassStatement *statement = cass_statement_new(result.c_str(), 0);

        CassFuture *result_future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
        cass_future_wait(result_future);

        if (cass_future_error_code(result_future) == CASS_OK) {
//            cout << "insert ok" << endl;
        }
        else {
            const char *message;
            size_t message_length;
            cass_future_error_message(result_future, &message, &message_length);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to run query: '%.*s'\n", (int) message_length,
                    message);

            cerr << "index : " << row << endl;
        }

        cass_statement_free(statement);
        cass_future_free(result_future);

        if (row % 1000 == 0)
        {
//            usleep(1000000);
//            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
//            cass_se
        }

    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    cout << "duration: " << duration.count() << endl;


}


int main() {

    /* Setup and connect to cluster */
    connect_future = NULL;
    cluster = cass_cluster_new();
    session = cass_session_new();

    /* Add contact points */
//    cass_cluster_set_contact_points(cluster, "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3");
    cass_cluster_set_contact_points(cluster, "127.0.0.1");

    /* Provide the cluster object as configuration to connect the session */
    connect_future = cass_session_connect(session, cluster);

    if (cass_future_error_code(connect_future) == CASS_OK) {
        CassFuture *close_future = NULL;

        insertQ();

        /* Close the session */
        close_future = cass_session_close(session);
        cass_future_wait(close_future);
        cass_future_free(close_future);
    } else {
        /* Handle error */
        const char *message;
        size_t message_length;
        cass_future_error_message(connect_future, &message, &message_length);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect: '%.*s'\n", (int) message_length,
                message);
    }

    cass_future_free(connect_future);
    cass_cluster_free(cluster);
    cass_session_free(session);

    return 0;
}
```

its works and writes about 90000 rows and then falls with this error:
`index : 91627
Unable to run query: 'Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.'
..`

and continues, I can execute 'SELECT' queries but after this 'INSERT's fails. unitl I restart the cassandra servcice.

Whats the problem?
My system: Ubuntu 14.04 x64, 8 gig ram, cassandra 2.1.4 (from cassandra debian repositories with default configrations)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming back from Cassandra.  It indicates that less than the amount of replicas required responded to your read/write request within the period of time configured in cassandra.  Since you are not specifying a consistency level, all that is required is that one node responds and it isn't within the write timeout.  The most relevant configurations to look at in cassandra.yaml are:

```
write_request_timeout_in_ms (default 2000ms)
read_request_timeout_in_ms (default: 5000ms)
range_request_timeout_in_ms (default: 10000ms)
```

Since you are doing inserts, write_request_timeout_in_ms is probably the most relevant configuration.

What's likely happening is that you are overwhelming your cassandra cluster.  Have you looked a cpu utilization/disk io/memory utilization on the server while running your test?

The interesting thing is that your code only ever does 1 INSERT at a time, is this correct?  I would expect that this should be fine, but maybe what is happening is that this is putting intense pressure on your memory heap in cassandra and it can't flush data fast enough, so it becomes backed up while writing to disk.   You should take a look at your cassandra system.log (usually in /var/log/cassandra if on linux) and see if there are any suspicious messages about long garbage collections (look for GCInspector) or memtable pressure.

Comment: thanks @Andy, after your answer I guess this is flushing problem, cassandra heap (1.5g max) fills rapidly and it stops the writing.  
and yes, I see messages about memtable pressure in logs, so what can I do? (there is no notable pressure on my core i3 cpu)

Comment: You should either increase your heap or throttle the rate at which you send your requests.  Since it seems you are doing everything locally it seems very possible for you to overwhelm your cassandra instance if the heap is that low.  What kind of disk are you using (is it an ssd)?  How active does it seem (check out iostat)?

Comment: my disks are magnetic and before fail I add 500 row/s and this seems huge.  
I'm going to test with lower speed (100 rows/s) in my commodity computer and I'll come back again, thanks again!

Comment: I change the commitlog_segment_size_in_mb to 8mb (from 32mb) and every things works like a charm.  
It seems my disk is slower than handle 32mb commit during continues insert.  
But there is a question (not SO proper question maybe): why my cassandra hangs (stop accepting INSERT for a long time) when face with this problem? (and nodetool flush doesn't work so). I except that cassandra backs on the line after 10 seconds (after a flush complete) but it doesn't!